# How to sync an iOS over the air (OTA) build back to iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, adhoc

I have an Ad Hoc build that I distributed to my iPad via OTA distribution using TestFlight. When I sync my iPad with iTunes, the OTA distributed app is not copied to the iTunes Library like the rest of the apps on my device that I downloaded from the App Store. The app icon is visible in the device screens section of the Apps tab for the device, but it does not appear in the "Sync Apps" list nor does it appear in the iTunes Library.

This is important because some of my users were having trouble sync-ing with iTunes after installing my app and downloading lots of content onto their device. I believe I've fixed that problem but now I seem to have no way to test the solution with an OTA distributed build.

Is there any way to get iTunes to sync an app that was installed on the device through OTA distribution?

Comment: This isn't a question related to programming. Have you contacted Test Flight support about this issue?

Comment: I've seen many Q&A's on SO about Ad Hoc and OTA distribution, so I think it's relevant. I'm not convinced the problem is with TestFlight, it may have to do with OTA distribution in general (I just happen to be using TestFlight.) I did search the TestFlight FAQ and nothing turned up. I haven't contacted them directly yet.

Comment: Good thing it takes 4 more votes to close the question :)

Comment: Should not be closed.  Part of app development is deployment.  This is not a TestFlight question.  I'm encountering the same issue with OTA apps signed with enterprise certs.

I would really appreciate getting to the bottom of this too!  @James-Richards

Answer (score 2):

You should post a new binary to TestFlight which will send your testers an email with a link to the build. From what I've gathered, the app is still going to be an Ad-Hoc app regardless of how it is distributed and probably will not sync to iTunes, it will however show up under the installed apps section for your device within the Xcode organizer.

I agree with @Alan that you should try and talk to TestFlight's support/forums for help with this.

Comment: I've asked the same question on the TestFlight forum. Is there a way I can close the question myself. I'm relatively new to SO and did not mean to offend.

Comment: I don't think you can flag questions until you get enough rep. I went ahead and flagged it at "too localized" for you. I recently started using TestFlight myself, but I haven't run into syncing problems yet.